# Use of make and making

Tags: syntax

My wife and I got into a discussion in the use of make and making.

Her sentence: Gabriel was make a living working as .....

I told her she should say "was making" and not "was make." She said I was wrong,  because she was taught, in her ESL class that "was make" is correct.

Is there a rule that covers this?

Comment: Robert is probably not a learner of English himself, but it appears his wife is and it seems to me that this question would be better answered by someone versed in ESL methods.

Comment: I cannot think of any context in which the verb phrase "was make" could be grammatical. After the auxiliary "was" (or any other part of "be", the only grammatical verbal forms are the present participle (-ing) and the past participle (-ed etc.).

Answer (score 4):

'Was Making' is the past progressive tense, you are right. 
See here for many other examples http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/tenses/past_progressive.htm